# net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "@" "@"

Tags: java

When I add variable statement like this in my SQL in mybatis:

```
set @update_id := 0;
```

this is my full statement:

```
set @update_id := 0;
        UPDATE r_room_seat s
        SET s.status = 1,
        s.user_id = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then #{user1.id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then #{user2.id,jdbcType=BIGINT}
            else -1 end
        ),
        s.robot_flag = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then #{user1.isRobot,jdbcType=INTEGER}
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then #{user2.isRobot,jdbcType=INTEGER}
            else 0 end
        )
        WHERE s.status = 0
        and s.online = 1
        and s.tenant_id = #{queryParam.tenantId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
        and s.room_play_id in (
            select room_play_id
            from (
                select room_play_id as room_play_id
                from r_room_seat
                where status = 0
                and app_id = 4
                and tenant_id = #{queryParam.tenantId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
                group by room_play_id
                having count(*) = 2
                limit 1
            ) a
        )
        and s.room_id = #{queryParam.roomTypeId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
        LIMIT 2;
        select
        <include refid="Base_Column_List"/>
        from r_room_seat
        where room_play_id = 5
        limit 1;
```

but throw this error:

```
### Cause: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: set @update_id := 0;
        UPDATE r_room_seat s
        SET s.status = 1,
        room_play_id = (SELECT @update_id := max(room_play_id)),
        s.user_id = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then ?
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then ?
            else -1 end
        ),
        s.robot_flag = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then ?
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then ?
            else 0 end
        )
        WHERE s.status = 0
        and s.online = 1
        and s.room_play_id in (
            select room_play_id
            from (
                select room_play_id as room_play_id
                from r_room_seat
                where status = 0
                and app_id = 4
                group by room_play_id
                having count(*) = 2
                limit 1
            ) a
        )
        and s.room_id = ?
        LIMIT 2;
        select
         
        
        id, room_play_id, room_id, user_id, creator, recent_active, deleted, sort, updated_time,
        created_time, `status`, robot_flag, app_id, app_mark, `online`, version
     
        from r_room_seat
        where room_play_id = @update_id
        limit 1;
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:30) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:149) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:76) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor358.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.2.jar!/:2.0.2]
    ... 114 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.exceptions.MybatisPlusException: Failed to process, please exclude the tableName or statementId.
 Error SQL: set @update_id := 0;
        UPDATE r_room_seat s
        SET s.status = 1,
        room_play_id = (SELECT @update_id := max(room_play_id)),
        s.user_id = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then ?
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then ?
            else -1 end
        ),
        s.robot_flag = (
            case when s.seat_num = 1
            then ?
            when s.seat_num = 2
            then ?
            else 0 end
        )
        WHERE s.status = 0
        and s.online = 1
        and s.room_play_id in (
            select room_play_id
            from (
                select room_play_id as room_play_id
                from r_room_seat
                where status = 0
                and app_id = 4
                group by room_play_id
                having count(*) = 2
                limit 1
            ) a
        )
        and s.room_id = ?
        LIMIT 2;
        select
         
        
        id, room_play_id, room_id, user_id, creator, recent_active, deleted, sort, updated_time,
        created_time, `status`, robot_flag, app_id, app_mark, `online`, version
     
        from r_room_seat
        where room_play_id = @update_id
        limit 1;
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.toolkit.ExceptionUtils.mpe(ExceptionUtils.java:39) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.parser.AbstractJsqlParser.parser(AbstractJsqlParser.java:74) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.handlers.AbstractSqlParserHandler.sqlParser(AbstractSqlParserHandler.java:76) ~[mybatis-plus-extension-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.plugins.PaginationInterceptor.intercept(PaginationInterceptor.java:155) ~[mybatis-plus-extension-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.prepare(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.prepareStatement(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:94) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.executor.MybatisSimpleExecutor.doQuery(MybatisSimpleExecutor.java:66) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.pagehelper.PageInterceptor.intercept(PageInterceptor.java:108) ~[pagehelper-5.1.11.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:49) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at tk.mybatis.orderbyhelper.OrderByHelper.intercept(OrderByHelper.java:115) ~[orderby-helper-0.0.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin.invoke(Plugin.java:61) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.query(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar!/:3.5.2]
    ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.JSQLParserException: null
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:128) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.parser.AbstractJsqlParser.parser(AbstractJsqlParser.java:60) ~[mybatis-plus-core-3.2.0.jar!/:3.2.0]
    ... 154 common frames omitted
Caused by: net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "@" "@"
    at line 1, column 5.

Was expecting one of:

    "ACTION"
    "ANY"
    "BYTE"
    "CASCADE"
    "CAST"
    "CHAR"
    "COLUMN"
    "COLUMNS"
    "COMMENT"
    "COMMIT"
    "DESCRIBE"
    "DO"
    "DOUBLE"
    "ENABLE"
    "END"
    "EXTRACT"
    "FIRST"
    "FN"
    "FOLLOWING"
    "IF"
    "INDEX"
    "INSERT"
    "INTERVAL"
    "ISNULL"
    "KEY"
    "LAST"
    "LEFT"
    "MATERIALIZED"
    "NEXTVAL"
    "NO"
    "NULLS"
    "OPEN"
    "OPTIMIZE"
    "OVER"
    "PARTITION"
    "PATH"
    "PERCENT"
    "PRECISION"
    "PRIMARY"
    "PRIOR"
    "RANGE"
    "REPLACE"
    "RIGHT"
    "ROW"
    "ROWS"
    "SEPARATOR"
    "SET"
    "SIBLINGS"
    "TABLE"
    "TEMP"
    "TEMPORARY"
    "TOP"
    "TRUNCATE"
    "TYPE"
    "UNSIGNED"
    "VALUE"
    "VALUES"
    "XML"
    "ZONE"
    <K_DATETIMELITERAL>
    <K_DATE_LITERAL>
    <S_IDENTIFIER>
    <S_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER>

    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.generateParseException(CCJSqlParser.java:20951) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.jj_consume_token(CCJSqlParser.java:20798) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.RelObjectNameExt(CCJSqlParser.java:3033) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Set(CCJSqlParser.java:612) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.SingleStatement(CCJSqlParser.java:185) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParser.Statements(CCJSqlParser.java:466) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    at net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.CCJSqlParserUtil.parseStatements(CCJSqlParserUtil.java:126) ~[jsqlparser-2.1.jar!/:na]
    ... 155 common frames omitted
```

this is the package I am using:

```
 api "com.baomidou:mybatis-plus-boot-starter:3.2.0"
```

what should I do to fix it? mybatis-plus not support user variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add sqlparse filter in your mapper:

```
@SqlParser(filter = true)
RoomSeat selectMultiRoomSeatForUpdateEnhance(@Param("queryParam") Map<String, Object> queryParam,
                                                 @Param("user1") User user1,
                                                 @Param("user2") User user2);
```

fix it.

Comment: what's the package name of @SqlParser ?  I can't find the annotation while my mybatis-plus-boot-starter version is 3.5.3.2

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to be a dependency issue for me. This is the query I ran with the older version of the jsqlparser library:

```
"SELECT COLUMN FROM OLDTABLE a GROUP BY stringcol = 'AAA'"
```

The older version of the jsqlParser, throws the JSQLParserException error:

```
Error while executing SQL "SELECT stringCol = 'AAA' from DATASET group by stringCol = 'AAA'": Remote driver error: JDBCException: Error parsing SQL 'SELECT stringCol = 'AAA' from DATASET group by stringCol = 'AAA'' -> JSQLParserException: Encountered unexpected token: "=" "="'.
```

After updating the jsqlParser library to the latest version from 'com.github.jsqlparser:jsqlparser:4.0' to 'com.github.jsqlparser:jsqlparser:4.4'. The error was resolved.

Here is a link to the repo where you can find their release docs - https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser